# [function.rename]: No error in

Tags: php, directory, rename

I do want to decrease the first part of the folders which are contained on the server when I delete a field in a database.

my folders are like : `1-Guerlain`, `2-Chanel`, `3-Diesel`. So when the first folder is deleted I want for the other folders to be like `1-Chanel`, `2-Diesel`.

This is my code :

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file)
{
    if($file->isDot()) continue;

    if($file->isDir())
    {
        $parts = explode('-', $file->getFilename());

        if ($parts[0] > $_GET['id_folder']) {
            $old = "./" . $parts[0] . "-" . $parts[1] . "";
            $new = "./" . ($parts[0] - 1) . "-" . $parts[1] . "";
            rename($old, $new);
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following error : **Warning: rename(./2-Chanel,./1-Chanel) [function.rename]: No error in C:\wamp\www\pcqsp-scratch\admin.php on line 196** and the folder doesn't be renamed.

How can I achieve this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the full path for [rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

```
$parts = explode('-', $file->getFilename());
$path = $file->getPath();

$old = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $parts[0] . "-" . $parts[1] . "";
$new = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ($parts[0] - 1) . "-" . $parts[1] . "";
rename($old, $new);
```